# mod_rewrite not rewriting url with a subdomain and folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm starting to learn mod_rewrite and experiencing a problem that I can't solve myself.

I have an url: `http://abc.domain.com/en/page.php?id=1`
which I want to rewrite to `http://abc.domain.com/en/1` when a customer visits it.

I've tried something like this

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/$ /vacancies.php?id=$1
```

but it doesn't really work. I believe the problem is with path as my site located on subdomain(abc) and in folder(en)

I would really appreciate pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in your `abc.domain.com/en/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ vacancies.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: just tried it putting this into both abc.domain.com and abc.domain.com/en and it's not working :( I see the same ?id=1 etc link :(

Comment: i wouldn't not recommend to put both .htaccess in both folders. i updated my answer. What does page.php do?

Comment: sorry for not expressing myself clearly, i tried once in / and once in /en/ but i haven't tried putting htaccess in to both folders. And sadly the code you edited above does not work for me :( What could possibly be the reason for that?

Comment: page.php was just as an example, there's only 1 file which is vacancies.php?id=$id that grabs vacancies by id

Comment: can you tell me your folder structure? is `en` an empty folder? do you have an .htaccess in the `/`?

Comment: sure, here it is :::
`/` - is an empty folder  (no .htaccess file there)
`/en` - is a folder where main site is located (including index.php and vacancies.php and .htaccess)

predicting next question - yes, mod_rewrite is enabled since this works perfectly : 
    `RewriteRule ^vacancies.php$ test.php`
it redirect me to nonexistent test.php when i hit vacancies.php

. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5961/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-mrkrabs)